# How to let ffmpeg use back same bitrate when encode video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, mp4, mpeg4

I have an mp4 file encoded using mpeg4 with a size of 20MB
When I checked the details of it, it said it has a 308k variable bitrate

Then, when I encoded it into h264, ffmpeg converted it with a constant 800k bitrate
As a result, the file size became 60MB

How do I get the bitrate information from the original video and then match the bitrate when encoding?

When I compared the result with Handbrake, I noticed that Handbrake automatically lowered down the bitrate, which produced  a lower file size. How did Handbrake estimate the bitrate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffprobe to get the details of a video. Ffprobe is included when you install ffmpeg, and it is used to grab details of a video.

For example:

```
ffprobe video.mp4
```

Will return something looking like this:

```
...
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.51.100
  Duration: 00:00:16.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 932 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 795 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Vireo Ears v2.6.2
```

Now you can find the bitrate for the original video (in this case, it is 932kb/s for the video, and 128kb/s for the audio)

If I wanted to copy these bitrates and convert to h264, I would then do:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec h264 -b:v 932k -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

This may not necessarily preserve the quality of the original video, and the size may not necessarily be the same, but you will have the exact same average bitrate.

If you want to preserve the exact quality, use `-crf 0` for a lossless output, but the filesize may be a lot bigger. If you want visually lossless quality, change the `-crf` value to between 18-23. This will make the filesize smaller than when using `-crf 0` and will visually look pretty much the same.

Ffmpeg offers greater customization than handbrake, and while I don't know exactly everything that Handbrake uses, I think they would most likely be using some similar to `ffprobe` to get the video data.

Comment: Instead of CRF 0 (which yields large file size and different color subsampling that is not always compatible) you can use a CRF between 18 and 23 which – depending on the original quality of the video – will look almost the same.

Comment: Oh yeah - thanks for reminding me - forgot to say that those numbers are considered "visually" lossless. Will update the answer.